# Custom template for forms in Django?

Tags: django, forms, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

how do I a custom template for my django forms.

I want to do something like {{ myform.as_p }} but its render my fields structure (for easly use of bootstrap {{ myform.render_bootstrap3 }}).

Should I use formset? Theres a tutorial or example of his usage?

Or could I copy the as_p function and create a custom Base Forms with a custom function (render_bootstrap3) that is a copy of as_p but using my structure? Is that a good pratice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`form.as_p` is just a shortcut for rendering much more html code. [Here is the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template) on what the `.as_p` does.

Or, you can make your custom html, by looping through the form. Example:

```
{% for formfield in myform %}
     {{ formfield }}
     {{ formfield.errors }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I see. I could use a reusable template (base_form.html). I will take a look, thanks.